# Remove item from selection jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I declare an empty jQuery selection, `$foo`

```
var $foo = $();
console.log($foo.length); // 0
```

Then, at some point, `<div id="foo"></div>` gets added to the document.

```
$foo = $('#foo');
console.log($foo.length); // 1
```

I'd like to remove the element `$foo` by calling `.remove()` on the selection. I'd expect the selection to reflect the fact that the element is no longer in the DOM, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

```
$foo.remove();
console.log($foo.length); // 1
```

In the simple case where I'm removing the element in question, I can check the [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) property of the element using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
if ( $foo.prop('parentNode') )
   // Exists
else
   // Does not exist
```

But what if I remove `$foo`'s parent instead of `$foo`? What if `$foo` gets modified such that the original selector doesn't match the element? How can I reliably detect that `$foo` is no longer in the document? And ultimately, is there a way for this to be reflected in the original selection?

Comment: have you tried using the remove method like this $('#foo').remove(); ?

Comment: @VaibhavKatole the point is that I've already selected the element and that I want to be able to check at any point to see if it still exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-search for your found jQuery objects by using the `.find()` method:

```
var length = $(document).find($foo).length;
```